# Pressing tab in NSTextField selects all text instead of going to next control

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I have multiple views all work fine but for some reason a view does not focus the next control when typing the tab key. Instead it selects all text of the current NSTextField.

I am forgetting something really stupid here; can anyone help me on this?

So it's an NIB containing a NSView.
On the view are two NSTextFields, pressing tab in one will not advance to next but instead select all text in current.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found it myself.
For anyone in the future having a similar problem:

If you are going to dynamic replace views in a NSWindow or NSView using addSubView or replaceSubView command you need to tell the NSWindow to recalculate the ViewLoop using NSWindow's recalculateKeyViewLoop or setAutorecalculatesKeyViewLoop

More info here:
http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/195341-nested-nsviews-and-keyboard-focus.html